# Reductions in Descriptive Complexity

Tags: lo.logic, reductions, descriptive-complexity

Reducing one problem to another are well known in various settings, such as many-one, randomized, truth-table, logspace or a whole slew of other reductions. Descriptive complexity can alternately characterize problems in $\mathsf{NP}$ using Logics, like e.g. extensions of first-order logic and others ([see here for an introduction](http://www.ams.org/notices/199510/immerman.pdf)). So, it is natural to ask how to approach reductions in this context. Are there reductions, based on first-order, or second-order logics used in Descriptive Complexity, or even completeness under these reductions for descriptive complexity?

Answer (score 7):

Standard notions of reduction used in Descriptive Complexity are [first-order reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_reduction) and the weaker first-order projection. Definitions of both these notions are found in [Immerman's book on Descriptive Complexity](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~immerman/book/descriptiveComplexity.html).